# Django admin on saving Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, django

Try to save an object in admin but get an error

> Field 'site_id' doesn't have a default value

user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):   
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='users', default=1)
```

review model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='reviews')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Review Title')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Your Review')
```

admin:

```
@register(Review)
class ReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

i user Django==1.6.11 and MySQL==5.7.14

Comment: can you please show you query for that table.

Answer (score 1):

There will be many reason for that ,

**1.** Try to add auto-increment in you primary key for that table .

**2.** In your query for that table try to start query with your id  for example if you are creating table try to start with your primary key .

[Check this link it may also help you](http://old.webit.ca/2012/01/field-id-doesnt-have-a-default-value/)

The following error came up on a project built on Django and MySQL:
“Warning: Field ‘id’ doesn’t have a default value”

At first, it seemed as though Django was responsible. However, a quick Google search proved this was an issue with MySQL.

Some solutions returned by the search required the programmer/administrator to export and recreate the database, but the solution proved a lot more simple. For a table named auth_user, the following MySQL command fixes the above error message:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The above command resets the ID field of the auth_user table to an auto-incremented integer of length 11, fixing the error message for good.